# Output not matching expectations

Tags: python

I'm trying to enumerate a large txt file for better visibility, and the only requirement I have is that it should split large chunks of text if they are made out of more than 3 sentences. But the code leaves an empty line after each line that is filled, which should not happen.

```
import re

# define the input and output file paths
input_file_path = "book1.txt"
output_file_path = "output4.txt"

# define the maximum number of sentences allowed in a line
max_sentences = 3

# initialize the line number counter
line_num = 1

# read the input file
with open(input_file_path, "r") as input_file:
    # open the output file for writing
    with open(output_file_path, "w") as output_file:
        # iterate over each line in the input file
        for line in input_file:
            # split the line into sentences
            sentences = re.split("(?<!\w\.\w.)(?<![A-Z][a-z]\.)(?<=\.|\?)\s", line.strip())
            # if the line contains more than the maximum number of sentences, split it
            if len(sentences) > max_sentences:
                # initialize the buffer for the current line
                buffer = ""
                # iterate over each sentence in the line
                for sentence in sentences:
                    # split the sentence into words
                    words = sentence.strip().split()
                    # initialize the buffer for the current sentence
                    sentence_buffer = ""
                    # iterate over each word in the sentence
                    for word in words:
                        # if the buffer has reached the maximum number of sentences, write it to the output file
                        if len(buffer.strip().split("\n")) == max_sentences:
                            output_file.write(str(line_num) + ". " + buffer.strip() + "\n")
                            line_num += 1
                            buffer = ""
                        # add the current word to the buffer for the current sentence
                        sentence_buffer += word + " "
                    # write the current sentence buffer to the current line buffer
                    buffer += sentence_buffer.strip() + " "
                # write the remaining buffer to the output file
                if buffer:
                    output_file.write(str(line_num) + ". " + buffer.strip() + "\n")
                    line_num += 1
            else:
                # write the original line to the output file
                output_file.write(str(line_num) + ". " + line.strip())
                if sentences:
                    output_file.write("\n")
                line_num += 1
```

The output I'm getting now looks like this

```
1. How are you today? Very well thank you.
2. 
3. How are you doing, it has been a while.
4.
```

But I don't what it to skip over a number each time. So it should look like this

```
1. How are you today? Very well thank you.
2. How are you doing, it has been a while.
3. 
4.
```

example of input:

‘Eh bien, vorst, Genua en Lucca zijn inmiddels niet veel meer dan landgoederen, landgoederen van de familie Bonaparte. Ik zeg u van tevoren, als u niet toegeeft dat we in oorlog zijn, als u zich veroorlooft alle zwijnerijen, alle gruweldaden van die antichrist – ik geloof echt dat hij dat is – te verdedigen, dan ken ik u niet meer, dan bent u niet langer mijn vriend, niet langer mijn trouwe dienaar, zoals u zelf altijd zegt. Goedenavond, goedenavond. Ik zie dat ik u aan het schrikken heb gemaakt. Gaat u zitten, heeft u nog iets te melden?’

Met die woorden begroette in juli 1805 de welbekende Anna Pavlovna Scherer, hofdame en vertrouwelinge van keizerin Maria Fjodorovna, de vooraanstaande en hooggeplaatste vorst Vasili, de eerste die op haar soiree arriveerde. Anna Pavlovna was al een paar dagen aan het hoesten, ze had de ‘griep’, zoals ze zelf zei (‘griep’ was toen een nieuw woord, dat nog maar door een enkeling werd gebezigd), en daarom deed ze geen dienst en kwam ze de deur niet uit. Op de briefjes, die ’s ochtends waren rondgebracht door een rode lakei, stond zonder onderscheid des persoons geschreven:

Als u, graaf (of vorst), niets beters in het vooruitzicht heeft en als het perspectief van een soiree bij een arme zieke u niet te veel afschrikt, dan verheug ik me erop u vandaag tussen zeven en tien uur bij mij te zien.

Anna Scherer

I tried to change the buffer, but this had no impact on the output.

Comment: Define “a sentence”

Comment: A sentence would be from a capital letter until a full stop.

Comment: What environment or operating system are you running your code on? Could you share part of your input file? 
I ran your code above on a Mac for an example input file where I had empty lines, lines with just one sentence, and lines with several sentences. The output file looks exactly the same as the input file but with line numbers, so I am not able to get extra newlines in the output with your code and my input file.

Comment: I added a part of the input file. I'm using visual studio code and running it in a Jupiter notebook file.

Comment: In the part of the code just after `# write the remaining buffer to the output file`, you do `if buffer:` This is False if the buffer is empty, but it's True if the buffer contains only whitespace - is that what you want?

Comment: Even with this added part of the input file, I am still getting the same result as before that is the same as the input but with line numbers. You can see how it looks here: http://codepad.org/kZTGk7C4. The first line has five full sentences, four ending with a period and the last one ending in a question mark, if you don't care that they are inside what someone is supposedly saying. The third line has three full sentences, two ending in a period and one ending in a colon.

Comment: So, I don't see unnecessary empty lines in the output at least when using the given example input but I do see that the sentence counting is not necessarily correct (see my previous comment).

Comment: @JarnoLamberg Yes I do get those results as well, but I don't want the empty line numbers, so each line number needs to be filled, so lines 2, 4 and 6 should not be empty.

Answer (score 1):

Your `else` branch starting from line 46 is what creates the empty numbered lines.

For an empty input line, the line 20 in code:

```
sentences = re.split("(?<!\w\.\w.)(?<![A-Z][a-z]\.)(?<=\.|\?)\s", line.strip())
```

will produce a result of `['']`.

Then, the check on line 22:

```
if len(sentences) > max_sentences:
```

is not true, and your code will jump to the `else` branch to line 46.

On line 48, you write the line number, period, and a space to the output file before checking whether you had actual content to write.

The check on line 49:

```
if sentences:
```

is true even for the content `['']`, so you write a newline on line 50, and then you increase the line counter.

Your `else` branch should check that the first sentence is not empty, for example, maybe like this:

```
        else:
            # write the original line to the output file
            if sentences[0] != '':
                output_file.write(str(line_num) + ". " + line.strip())
                output_file.write("\n")
                line_num += 1
```

With that change, you don't get empty numbered lines in the output.

Alternatively, you could remove the empty sentences from `sentences` after the split on line 20, and then you could check for the length of the `sentences` inside your `else` branch.